# Implement zstd compression with oracle advanced compression

Tags: oracle, compression, zstd

I am new to oracle database and using 19c version. I need to know if zstd algorithm can be implemented along with oracle advanced compression. I am able to implement zstd algorithm at RMAN level. Is there any way to choose the compression algorithm when using advanced compression in oracle? Thanks in advance!

**RMAN COMMAND OUTPUT FOR ENABLING ZSTD:**

```
RMAN> CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'ZSTD'
2> ;

new RMAN configuration parameters:
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'ZSTD' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE;
new RMAN configuration parameters are successfully stored

RMAN> show COMPRESSION ALGORITHM
2> ;

RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name DB9ZX are:
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'ZSTD' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE;
```

**EXPECTING FOR SYNTAX:**

```
SQL<>alter table xtbl row store compress advanced;

Table altered.

SQL<>alter table xtbl row store compress advanced zstd;
alter table xtbl row store compress advanced zstd
                                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option


SQL<>alter table xtbl row store compress zstd advanced;
alter table xtbl row store compress zstd advanced
                                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
```

Answer (score 1):

Compression for RMAN files is significantly different from compression for live tables and rows. You can't choose a specific algorithm like ZSTD for table compression.

The [Oracle Database Administrator's Guide has a section on table compression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-ED833867-4B7F-442E-A70C-9C19DAA8F445) which covers 4 types of compression and when you might prefer each one.

> When you use `basic table compression`, `warehouse compression`, or `archive compression`, compression only occurs when data is bulk loaded or array inserted into a table.

> `Advanced row compression` is intended for OLTP applications and compresses data manipulated by any SQL operation.

Warehouse and Archive compression use Hybrid Columnar Compression (which requires additional licensing) - [it dynamically chooses different (unspecified) compression algorithms based on the data type, etc.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/tables-and-table-clusters.html#GUID-A968B257-553F-45F7-88C8-620F04FFA48D) and is optimized for storage, not performance.

Oracle Database Concepts also has [a section on table compression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/tables-and-table-clusters.html#GUID-54EE5325-0894-4869-B3AD-8912D9B4A329) that goes into a little bit of detail about `advanced row compression`, which is optimized for OLTP performance. The relevant part for your question is that Oracle implemented their own simple compression algorithm ([just replacing duplicate values with symbol table references](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/logical-storage-structures.html#GUID-B248DC2A-3F65-42CF-ACA5-0B096CFCFC46)). You can't configure your own compression algorithm.

Comment: Apart from the documented algorithms for advanced compression, there is no option for custom settings for using third party algorithm in advanced compression. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find anything like that in the documentation.